# Remove some Google email headers from mbox/eml files

Tags: macos, shell, email, unix

I have a big email Archive hosted in iCloud/Mail.app, which was until last year on Google, but during the export import many emails have gotten some new Headers which make them look like they were sent/received in 2013, event though they are mostly from 2008/09.

The culprit is a Google header X-Received I believe. Now I'd like to remove all those unnecessary headers to get back my original email archive. All those emails are packed in an MBOX as .eml text files. So I'm thinking I could just edit them with a script...

Anybody got any hints/scripts etc. to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a really broad question and there are many ways you could go on about doing something like this. One way, as you mentioned would be to write up a script. Have you tried doing anything like this? And if so, would you please include it in your post?

Comment: If requirement is to remove the header from the file which contain multiple header then look for common contents of headers and use sed command to find and replace that line which contain header.

Comment: I don't have a script and no clue how to do it. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Thanks!